# Values returned from a DLL differ between straight g++ and qt using g++

Tags: c++, qt, dll, g++, qt-creator

I have written a dll that uses an abstract interface to allow access to the c++ class inside. When I load the library dynamically at run-time using the *LoadLibrary()* function using a simple console created in eclipse using g++ and call a function from within the dll I get the correct values returned. However when writing the same console program using qt-creator qt5 with the g++ compiler I get completely different results that are not correct.

All of this was written under Windows 7 64-bit but using the x86 side of it for the programs.

The code that calls the dll from eclipse looks as follows:

```
HMODULE hMod = ::LoadLibrary("libTestDll.dll");

if (hMod) {
    cout << "Library Loaded" << endl;
    CreateITestType create = (CreateITestType) GetProcAddress(hMod,
            "GetNewITest");

    ITest* test = create();

    std::cout << test->Sub(20, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Sub(20, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Add(20, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Add(13, 4) << std::endl;

   DeleteITestType del = (DeleteITestType) GetProcAddress(hMod,
   "DeleteITest");
    del(test);
    test = NULL;
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
   }
```

This returns:

```
Library Loaded
15
17
25
17
```

The code that calls the dll from qt looks as follows:

```
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary(TEXT("libTestDll.dll"));

if(hMod)
{
    CreateITestType create = (CreateITestType)GetProcAddress(hMod, "GetNewITest");
    DeleteITestType destroy = (DeleteITestType)GetProcAddress(hMod, "DeleteITest");

    ITest* test = create();

    std::cout << test->Sub(20, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Sub(20, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Add(20, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->Add(13, 4) << std::endl;

    destroy(test);
    test = NULL;

    FreeLibrary(hMod);
}
```

And This returns:

```
1
-17
25
24
```

Both programs have the imports:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "TestDll.h"
```

And finally the functions are implemented as follows:

```
int Test::Add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a+b);
}

int Test::Sub(int a, int b)
{
    return (a-b);
}
```

My question is where is the difference coming from seeing as the two programs are identical in both code and compiler, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Are compiler versions same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also rebuild the DLL with `qt-creator qt5 with the g++ compiler`? If not, then what you've discovered is that if you don't use the exact same compiler, compiler options and settings, defines, and pretty much every other aspect of the build system, C++ interfaces are not typically ABI compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not rebuild the dll using qt. I was under the impression that if using an abstract interface and using factory functions it became fairly compiler independent. I will have to check this.